Android Studio: Unresolved reference: photo_title
enter image description here
As you can see in above the above code, a Textview which has id: photo_title is not recognized even though I have created a TextView in content_photo_details.xml with the ID: photo_title.
I'm a beginner who's creating an Image display app using a tutorial. I want the app to display the photo alongside info when clicked. The app worked smoothly until now, it displayed all the photos one below other but when I try to include the code for displaying the full photo, I run into this problem.
I've provided the code for content_photo_details.xml and activity_photo_details.xml
PhotoDetailsActivity.kt:
package com.example.flickrbrowser
import android.os.Bundle
import com.example.flickrbrowser.databinding.ActivityPhotoDetailsBinding
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso

class PhotoDetailsActivity : BaseActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityPhotoDetailsBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityPhotoDetailsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
//      setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo_details)

        activateToolbar(true)

    val photo = intent.getSerializableExtra(PHOTO_TRANSFER) as Photo
        binding.photo_title.text = photo.title

    }
}

activity_photo_details.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".PhotoDetailsActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_photo_details" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

content_photo_details.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".PhotoDetailsActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_photo_details" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


Did you try doing an invalidate cache and restart in android studio? File > Invalidate Caches

It seems you have provided some missing code. However. I can guess your problem.
When id is "photo_title" in xml file. in kotlin file. it will be called "photoTitle". So, try accessing using binding.photoTitle.
